# Where is SQL Server Express service?

Tags: sql

I've installed SQL Server 2012 Express advanced edition on a clean (just OS without any third-party soft) w7x64 residing on VirtualBox 4.1.18. I’ve chosen every needed option to install, but after installation there is no SQL Server Express service running on guest OS on virtual machine. Also I have the same edition of SQL Server installed on my host OS which is also w7x64. Please give me any clues to what may be the cause of this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to diagnose:

1. Check in Control Panel -> Services that the SQL service is running
2. Try to connect from the local machine, type `osql -E -S localhost\sqlexpress` in a command prompt.

Comment: The SQL service is running, but it's not an express edition. I've tried osql -E -S localhost\sqlexpress, here what he writes: [SQL Server Native Client 11.0]SQL Server Network Interfaces: Error Locating
Server/Instance Specified [xFFFFFFFF].
[SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Login timeout expired
[SQL Server Native Client 11.0]A network-related or instance-specific error
has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not
found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server
is configured to allow remote connections.

Comment: The paradox is that I've done the same actions on deploying SQL server on VirtualBox as I did previously on the host pc where I didn't meet such an issue. The same distributive was used, the same settings applied and in one case everything is working properly but on virtual OS I have problems with missing express service. How can it be connected to dealing with VirtualBox?